# Auto-post to multiple sites like Posterous?

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-recommendation

I'd like to be able to autopost from my wordpress site (private wordpress.org, not on wordpress.com) to multiple sites with one plugin/hack from within wordpress. I'd like my posts to be able to be auto-posted (linked to) on facebook, identi.ca, twitter, posterous, etc. without multiple plugins. I've looked everywhere for a good plugin and they all seem to be site specific (for example just a twitter plugin). I need a one-stop shop like posterous, but since i have my own site i don't want the links going to posterous when they could be coming back to my official site. is this at all possible as of yet? if not, someone should step up and code it. thanks!

Comment: I doubt you will find one plugin that covers all services you want. People usually develop a plugin for a need they have themselves, and this might not include everything you need. However, there could be some plugins that use a similar interface, so it doesn't look like they come from different places. And the *someone* that should step up could also be you of course!

Comment: haha...maybe i will. i got some learnin' to be done. thanks for the push. i'll do some research.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ping.fm](http://ping.fm/) service with the plugin [Shorten2Ping](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shorten2ping/).

Comment: yeah. still the same problem. it would all link back to ping.fm and not my site.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [dlvr.it](http://dlvr.it/)

you just need the rss of your blog and it will be published to facebook, linkedin, googlebuz, Twitter and more....

I've been using it for months

Comment: oh wow. that looks nice. do they take credit like as in saying "via dlvr.it" or anything like that? I was considering @Jan Fabry's advice and just making one for wordpress, but if dlvr.it is transparent, i'm all for it.

Comment: It shows on facebook, it is very small and it doesn't bother, at least me.. :), in twitter it doesn't show any credit. don't know about other social networks.
I think that most of them if not all have take the credit :)